Numpy is not available (numpy has been installed
I tried running the code (i.e. "Basic Components") provided in BOTorch for Bayesian Optimization on my windows system Jupyter Notebook loaded via powershell.
https://botorch.org/docs/getting_started#basic-components
It keeps showing error messages that "Numpy is not available," but I have numpy installed as well as the other dependencies such as botorch. The code and error message are both shown below. I tried removing certain lines of the basic components code, and it seems to run with out "fit_gpytorch_mll(mll)." My numpy should be the newest version.
import torch
from botorch.models import SingleTaskGP
from botorch.fit import fit_gpytorch_mll
from gpytorch.mlls import ExactMarginalLogLikelihood
from botorch.models.transforms.outcome import Standardize

train_X = torch.rand(10, 2, dtype=torch.float64)
# explicit output dimension -- Y is 10 x 1
train_Y = 1 - (train_X - 0.5).norm(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
train_Y += 0.1 * torch.rand_like(train_Y)

gp = SingleTaskGP(train_X, train_Y, outcome_transform=Standardize(m=1))
mll = ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(gp.likelihood, gp)
fit_gpytorch_mll(mll)

`RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[9\], line 14
12 gp = SingleTaskGP(train_X, train_Y, outcome_transform=Standardize(m=1))
13 mll = ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(gp.likelihood, gp)
\---\> 14 fit_gpytorch_mll(mll)

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\botorch\\fit.py:103, in fit_gpytorch_mll(mll, closure, optimizer, closure_kwargs, optimizer_kwargs, \*\*kwargs)
100 if optimizer is not None:  # defer to per-method defaults
101     kwargs\["optimizer"\] = optimizer
\--\> 103 return FitGPyTorchMLL(
104     mll,
105     type(mll.likelihood),
106     type(mll.model),
107     closure=closure,
108     closure_kwargs=closure_kwargs,
109     optimizer_kwargs=optimizer_kwargs,
110     \*\*kwargs,
111 )

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\botorch\\utils\\dispatcher.py:93, in Dispatcher.__call__(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
91 func = self.__getitem__(types=types)
92 try:
\---\> 93     return func(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
94 except MDNotImplementedError:
95     # Traverses registered methods in order, yields whenever a match is found
96     funcs = self.dispatch_iter(\*types)

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\botorch\\fit.py:190, in \_fit_fallback(mll, \_, \_\_, closure, optimizer, closure_kwargs, optimizer_kwargs, max_attempts, warning_handler, caught_exception_types, \*\*ignore)
188 with catch_warnings(record=True) as warning_list, debug(True):
189     simplefilter("always", category=OptimizationWarning)
\--\> 190     optimizer(mll, closure=closure, \*\*optimizer_kwargs)
192 # Resolved warnings and determine whether or not to retry
193 done = True

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\botorch\\optim\\fit.py:92, in fit_gpytorch_mll_scipy(mll, parameters, bounds, closure, closure_kwargs, method, options, callback, timeout_sec)
89 if closure_kwargs is not None:
90     closure = partial(closure, \*\*closure_kwargs)
\---\> 92 result = scipy_minimize(
93     closure=closure,
94     parameters=parameters,
95     bounds=bounds,
96     method=method,
97     options=options,
98     callback=callback,
99     timeout_sec=timeout_sec,
100 )
101 if result.status != OptimizationStatus.SUCCESS:
102     warn(
103         f"`scipy_minimize` terminated with status {result.status}, displaying"
104         f" original message from `scipy.optimize.minimize`: {result.message}",
105         OptimizationWarning,
106     )

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\botorch\\optim\\core.py:93, in scipy_minimize(closure, parameters, bounds, callback, x0, method, options, timeout_sec)
91     bounds_np = None
92 else:
\---\> 93     bounds_np = get_bounds_as_ndarray(parameters, bounds)
95 if callback is None:
96     wrapped_callback = None

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\botorch\\optim\\utils\\numpy_utils.py:166, in get_bounds_as_ndarray(parameters, bounds)
164     if isinstance(upper, Tensor):
165         upper = upper.cpu()
\--\> 166     out\[index : index + size, 0\] = lower
167     out\[index : index + size, 1\] = upper
168 index = index + size

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\torch_tensor.py:1089, in Tensor.__array__(self, dtype)
1087     return self.numpy()
1088 else:
\-\> 1089     return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

RuntimeError: Numpy is not available

I tried removing certain lines of the basic components code, and it seems to run with out "fit_gpytorch_mll(mll)."`


Did you try to import numpy in the same script, to see if that works?

Hi, yes I did. I imported numpy and made sure that numpy was installed and up to date.

Hi, I tried most of the methods mentioned in the thread, but it has not fixed the issue. However, the problem appears to be very similar... simply numpy being unavailable even when the module is installed and numpy imported.

Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies. python -m pip check

Hi, the issue was resolved after I completely uninstalled Python and reinstalling it using Anaconda. Perhaps there were issues with compatibility of dependencies or python itself. Thanks.
